# fopen won't open files across network

Tags: php, fopen

I can use fopen to open local files but can't open files across network on a different machine. I can map the drives and look at the files but can't open them using fopen.

Comment: there is always an error message to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Please mention the OS and webserver (if the script is not run from CLI) you're using, because that can be quite relevant.

Comment: @wimvds: Very good point since he mentions "map the drives".

Comment: @Josh Yep, it probably is a permission problem if he's using Apache on Windows and running that with the default user (the Local System account, which doesn't have any network privileges).

Comment: If you're running on a MSWindows platform - then yes, IIS mysteriously seems to inherit permissions via NTLM - its not documented (AFAICT) and a nightmare for all sorts of reasons. Apache on Windows will run as the default user.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're running Apache on Windows (since you talk about "mapping" the drive):

If you used the defaults during installation then apache is running with the Local System account, which doesn't have any network privileges. So you have to make sure it runs as a (domain) user that can access the network drive(s). You can change this via Control Panel, Administrative Tools, Services (right click on Apache, select Properties and select a user on the Log On tab).

Answer (score 0):

In order to open remote files you need to have the php.ini setting "allow_url_fopen" enabled. Is that the case in your settings?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem and allow_url_fopen is enabled.