# PHP fopen() can't function

Tags: php, fopen

I facing problem with my PHP fopen() for read files.

The error is :

```
Warning: fopen(\\192.168.183.28\DIGI_PROG\M10\TEST1\P001.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\digi\index.php on line 72
```

and My PHP Code :

```
echo $fs = fopen("\\\\192.168.183.28\\DIGI_PROG\\M10\\TEST1\\P001.txt","r");
```

Strangely, when I try to open that URL, it's opened.
To make sure, the file is exist.

Any advice?

Comment: what is all those backslashes doing there. use forward slash for path even in windows

Comment: @presiuslitelsnoflek I tried, but still error same like before

Comment: Also, use single quotes for non-dynamic strings

Comment: UNC path is okay to be used in `fopen()` See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive). Maybe your problem is related to permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `fopen()`, the `file_get_contents()` function is the preferred way to read the contents of a file into a string. It will use memory mapping techniques if supported by your OS to enhance performance.

Like this:
`file_get_contents('http://192.168.183.28/DIGI_PROG/M10/TEST1/P001.txt');`

EDIT:
If you want to open a file which is on shared network resource, then use this (example, notice that there are no double slashes in the path):

`file_get_contents('/path/to/mount/path/to/file.txt');`

Note:

If you're opening a URI with special characters, such as spaces, you need to encode the URI with `urlencode()`.

Comment: you're suggesting an alternative URL. OP wants a file from shared network, but your URL is on web server.

Answer (score 0):

if you read the docs you will see that

```
resource fopen ( string $filename , string $mode [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )
```

where

```
filename is of the form "scheme://...", it is assumed to be a URL and PHP
```

I suggest that you use the following

```
fopen('http://192.168.183.28/DIGI_PROG/M10/TEST1/P001.txt','r')
```

or use file_get_contents (after making sure the allow_url_fopen is set to 1)

Comment: UNC path is not equal to URL.

Answer (score -1):

very basic try should be:

```
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} 
else 
{
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

If you get that file does not exist, its obvious that your path is wrong or file really does not exists, which should not be a case, since you checked it on file sistem.
Check spelling. 
i am not sure you should put so many backslashes there. 
Have you tried with fopen( \ \ 192.168.183...) ?

On the Windows platform, be careful to escape any backslashes used in the path to the file, or use forward slashes.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r");
?>
```

Hope this will help a little bit to find the reason
Regards
Vladimir

Comment: Use forward slash can avoid some escaping issues. Also, this answer does not tackle OP's problem.

Comment: He should find the reason why he can not open the file, right?
So if you read again, probably will notice that i am suggesting two simple steps:
- check if file does exists
- open file
so, why are you saying that it does not tackle the problem?
He will benefit from this checking if file exists before he try to open it will handle potential error as well.
And apparently your comment clearly points that you should read php documentation before you post "Use forward slash can avoid some escaping issues" as you can read it on php.net at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php
regards, V