# PHP can't access network drive but can if address is explicit

Tags: php, networking

I've been battling this problem for days now. I'm 100% sure is a user configuration thing somewhere but, i don't know where to look or what to change. Here is the problem. I have a file i want to read. It just contains 5 lines like "this is line 1, this is line 2 etc. It's for debugging purposes. I have 2 copies of this files. one lives locally and one lives on a network drive. I can access the file locally no problem. I can also access the file on the network drive if I specify the address as in \\192.168.0.16\geo\junk.txt. What I cannot do is to access the file via a mapped drive. as in U:\junk.txt where the U: is mapped to the 192.168... above. Below is my code. Again, after A LOT!!! of reading I've come to the conclusion that its a user perminsion thing between the machine the code lives in and the apache server that runs the code. I don't think the two are talking to each other. Just in case this is on a windows 7 machine apache 2.2.

```
<?php
#$theFile="\\\\192.168.0.16\\geo\\junk.txt"; #works fine
#$theFile="junk.txt"; #local file works fine
$theFile="U:\\junk.txt";  #mapped drive DOESN'T WORK AAARRRGGG!!!!! 
$handle = fopen($theFile, "r");
if($handle){
    while (!feof($handle)){
        $buffer = fgets($handle);
        echo $buffer."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't $theFile be "U:\\geo\\junk.txt"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read file on a network drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive)

Comment: Ksealey: Tried the "U:\\geo\\junk.txt" but didn't work. "U:\\junk.txt" should be the correct one. Dave: so, accoridng to the answer on the link provided this can't be done using a mapped drive?