# Accessing remote file system in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache, angular

I am trying to open an image that is kept on a shared network location, lets say P.
Copying the files from P to my server directory is not ideal as the files are updated frequently. It could be done as a last resort; I know that this would be ideal under regular circumstances, but I am working with some legacy systems.

I do not mind even having the client side fetch the images from P, if possible, as my 'clients' are follow workers who will be viewing these images from a location connected to P. My front end is Angular 2, backend PHP/Apache.

My workaround backend solution was:

```
$baseDir = "file://P:/Shop/Fabs/Pictures/pic1234.jpg";
$imageURL = $baseDir . $imageName;
$imageFile = fopen($imageURL, 'r');
$imageData = fread($imageFile, filesize($imageURL));

echo $imageData;
```

When this happens, I get

```
 fopen(file://P:/Shop/Fabs/Pictures/pic1234.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ....
```

I am expecting base64 image data.

I have "allow_url_fopen=On" in php.ini. P is mapped on my network drive (have tried going between ip literal and "P"). I can enter the URI into my browser and have the image appear.

Any help much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: use the network path \\COMPUTERNAME/somedir/shop/Fabs/Pictures/pic1234.jpg

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it brings me the same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive Your apache service user needs to be able to access the network path. If the user doesn't have permission it won't be able to access it. Set your apache to run under your windows/domain user account.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file on a network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive)