# Write to file on shared drive from apache server PHP

Tags: php

I have a program on an apache server that is attempting to write some data to a file which is located locally on a shared drive. No matter how many times I have tried to map to the drive, it does not work.

```
$myfile = fopen("\\plz100-nas1\Finance\Controller\xxx\xxx\xxx\Test.txt", "a") 
or die("Unable to open file!");

while($row = $oci->fetch($sqlExcelVer))
{
    fwrite($myfile,"\r\n");

    foreach($row as $key => $value)
    {
        if(gettype($value) == "object")
        {
            $value = $value -> load();          
        }
        fwrite($myfile, $value);
        fwrite($myfile, ",");
    }
}
?>
```

The above code is what I use to write to the file. The mapped location on my computer is the U:/ drive.

The complete location of the file is 
\\plz100-nas1\Finance\Controller\xxx\xxx\xxx\Test.txt

Can someone please help me find the error in my code.

Comment: Do you even have access rights ?

Comment: Yes, I originally thought that was the issue but I do

Comment: ```\``` is an escape character…

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double for the path and use error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive

Comment: I may be wrong in my understanding, but it seems that the program is looking for the location on the apache server. Is there an intermediate step I need to take to have it look on the windows machine?