# HTML PHP: show default IMG if the specified one does not exist using pictures of network location

Tags: php, html, image, if-statement, networking

I think this was already answered but i'm trying to show a picture based on a variable. If the Image does not exist it should show the default IMG.
The problem is that the images are both not being displayed. The images are stored on a server accessible from the network. The images have $IDnr.jpg as name.

```
<?php
  $filename="\\Network-server\map\map\map\map\<?php echo $IDnr; ?>.jpg";
  if(is_readable($filename)){
     $fileToShow=$filename;
  }else{
    $fileToShow="\\Network-server\map\map\map\map\defaultIMG.jpg";
  }
    echo '<img class="imageclass" src="<?php echo $fileToShow; ?>"/>';
?>
```

Comment: Try echoing your $filename variable and access that path to check whether the resource (image) is accessible

Comment: First of all replace this `echo '<img class="imageclass" src="'.$fileToShow.'"/>';`

Comment: @adi i tried it and it's not showing anything.

Comment: @ManojKumar I replaced it and the error still persists.

Comment: Yes.. it means your string is incorrect. Try the way @monkeyzeus suggested. You will need to concat and use backslashes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to interpolate strings properly:

```
$IDnr = 'filename';

$filename = "\\\\Network-server\\map\\map\\map\\map\\".$IDnr.".jpg";

echo $filename;
```

Output:

```
\\Network-server\map\map\map\map\filename.jpg
```

Backslashes `\` state that the following character should literally be used so you need to double up when you literally want one.

String concatenation is done via `.` notation so you cannot just echo something in the middle of string building.

---

Update per the comments:

> Hi, I followed the instructions on the pages and it seemed to be a problem with user rights of PHP. The error has now disappeared but the picture is still not showing.

The reason that the image is not showing is because your code is trying to use a direct network path to retrieve an asset so you have a few options.

**Option 1: Link to the network path using `file:`**

A network path only works for visitors which are actually on the network and have the right to read the resource so you could do something like `echo '<img src="file:'.$filename.'"/>';` but the network limitation is probably not desirable.

**Option 2: Read the file contents and provide it as an inline image**

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( file_get_contents( $filename ) ).'"/>';
```

The biggest issue with this is that it is not cache-able by web browsers and PHP has to read from network location and load **EVERY SINGLE** image into memory for all user requests so this can have severe performance implications.

**Option 3: Mount the network location**

This one is the most involved but is the most proper solution. You need to figure out how to either symlink or mount the network location so that you can have normal web links such as:

```
echo '<img src="http://example.com/map/map/map/'.$IDnr.'.jpg"/>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I tried the above and came up with this:    <?php
$filename="\\\\network-server\\map\\map\\map\\map\".$IDnr".".jpg";
if(file_exists($filename)){
    $fileToShow=$filename;
}else{
    $fileToShow="\\\\network-serverl\\map\\map\\map\\map\\defaultIMG.jpg";
}
echo '<img class="imageclass" src="'.$fileToShow.'"/>';
?> Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MaxTheuws It sounds like neither image exists or PHP does not have rights to access  them.

Comment: The images exist. I can access them via Windows Explorer. I can open them via HTML <img> but not when i try to run this PHP script.

Comment: @MaxTheuws PHP usually runs under a different username compared to Windows Explorer. You will need to check privileges and make sure PHP can access the network drive.

Comment: @MaxTheuws you can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive for clues on how to debug network share issues. Above all else, make sure you have turned on all error reporting via `error_reporting( E_ALL );`

Comment: @MaxTheuws If you cannot `file_get_contents( $filename );` without errors then that's how you know if you still have an issue. `file_get_contents()` will issue an `E_WARNING` so it is super important to turn on error reporting.

Comment: file_get_contents says permission denied. I'll go and troubleshoot via the link you gave me.

Comment: @MaxTheuws Sounds good and good luck! If you feel that my answer helped you overall then please feel free to accept it by using the checkmark below the up/down vote arrows, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, these answers are all really helping me. I haven't been programming in PHP for very long so i can use all the help i can get.

Comment: Hi, I followed the instructions on the pages and it seemed to be a problem with user rights of PHP. The error has now disappeared but the picture is still not showing.

Answer (score -2):

There is an error in first line, instead of

```
$filename="\\Network-server\map\map\map\map\<?php echo $IDnr; ?>.jpg";
```

write

```
$filename="\\Network-server\map\map\map\map\\".$IDnr.".jpg";
```

Comment: [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) Please don't edit code in answers, ESPECIALLY when your edit causes syntax errors.