# Unable to access network drive in PHP

Tags: php, windows, wamp

I'm facing an issue in PHP where I can't open a file located on a network drive for reading

I have tried a lot of different path name

```
$file = fopen('G:/Folder/vak.xlsx', 'r');
$file = fopen('//10.X.X.X/Folder/vak.xlsx', 'r');
$file = fopen('\\\\10.X.X.X\\Folder\\vak.xlsx', 'r');
```

But I always get the same error

> Could not open "G:/Folder/vak.xlsx" for reading! File does not exist.

I have read a lot of post related to this issue and try all the solutions that i've found, but nothing works.

The network drive is mapped on the server under G: and the apache service is launched with a domain user account who's allowed to access to the network drive.

The server is running WAMP (Apache + Mysql + PHP 5.6)

I don't know why it's not working. Maybe someone has already solved this issue.

EDIT :
I have also try to use `scandir()` like this :

```
$files = scandir('\\\\10.X.X.X\\');
var_dump($files);
```

And I get

> The network name cannot be found. (code: 67)

Comment: replace `/` with `\` in the first line: `$file = fopen('G:\Folder\vak.xlsx');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file on a network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive)

Comment: Thank for your answer @SaeedM., but same issue

Comment: Already try solutions from this post @Zeitounator, but not working :-(

Comment: try : `$file = fopen('G:\\Folder\\vak.xlsx');`

Comment: Same, i get `failed to open stream: No such file or directory `

Comment: Does this file exists at this location ?

Comment: Yes of course, I can access it under windows explorer on the server

Comment: The problem is most likely that the network drive is mapped on your computer for your user, not for the user who runs PHP (which is the web servers user) so PHP won't have any G:

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have seen this solution on another post, but my apache server is running under a domain account who has rights to access this location. I have also try with the IP address, but same issue

Comment: can you `fopen('G:\\', 'r');` ? And `fopen('\\\\10.X.X.X\\', 'r');` ?

Comment: No, I can't. I have also try to mount the drive under a new letter and specify the same account but not working. Maybe this is an apache configuration issue ?

Comment: The device namespace is divided. There's a local, *per-logon* mount directory (e.g. "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logon ID>") that shadows the global mount directory, "\Global??". Device mountpoints such as "C:" are object symlinks that ultimately resolve to a device in the "\Device" object directory. For example, for a UNC path it's "\Device\Mup", plus an optional component with a pre-resolved provider and logon session, plus the server and share components, and finally the file path on the share. Mapped drives such as "G:" are local mountpoints that are pre-resolved to improve response time.

Comment: Since a mapped drive is local to a logon session, it has to be created from that session, such as with the `net use` command, which can also include required credentials. The system caches the connection with the established credentials in association with the logon session.