# PHP Create File on Network Share folder

Tags: php, iis, fopen, network-share

I am trying to create file on network share folder. This network share folder is mounted on local machine as Z:

I want to create file on Z: For this I run following code

```
$f = fopen("z:\abc\file\test.txt","w") or die("Can't open file");
```

I also tried it below case

```
$f = fopen("//xx.xx.xx.xx/share/abc/file/test.txt","w") or die("Can't open file");
$f = fopen("\\\\xx.xx.xx.xx\\share\\abc\\file\\test.txt","w") or die("Can't open file");
```

It gives below error

```
Warning: fopen(z:\abc\file\test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\test.php on line 3
can't open file
```

I am able to open this share folder and also shared with everyone group with full control access.

I also follwed [Read file on a network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14367687/read-file-on-a-network-drive) & [fopen won't open files across network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874796/fopen-wont-open-files-across-network) but it not worked for me

Comment: IIS has a config for enabling access to "parent paths" - I've never tried a mapped path with or without this on, but it is at least something to look at and try?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the iis user don't have rights to the network resources.
The only method (that i know) to write on network share is to open the share to all, to make this you need to use gpedit.msc on fileserver.

The path in gpedit.msc is:
Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options

The key to modify is:
*Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymously
This security setting determines which network shares can accessed by anonymous users.
Default: None specified.*